# A classe de serviços não reconhece os métodos da classe HttpClientModule do Angular 10

Tags: angular

Essa é a estrutura do meu pequeno projeto;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E conseguir importar o modulo http no meu projeto como podem ver abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém depois de importar o método para minha classe de serviços gera erros no código porque ele não reconhece o método **get** como podem ver abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso de ajuda para corrigir isso, estou com a versão do **Angular 10** e não entendo porque está gerando esse erro.

Se eu navegar direto para a classe HttpClientModule eu consigo localizar o método **get** que não está sendo reconhecida na minha classe de serviços, o que será que houve de errado

Comment: No módulo vc importa o módulo **`import { HttpClientModule } `**, no service vc usa as classes com os métodos **`import { HttpClient }`**

Comment: Nossa cara, eu nunca iria imagina que fosse dessa forma, do angula 2 até o 10 mudou algumas coisas e me deixou confuso, muito obrigado, pode postar sua resposta para eu marcar como correta.

Comment: Acho que não precisa de uma resposta pra isso não, até pq, mesmo na versão 2 é o mesmo jeito, no service  vc importa a classe com os métodos e no módulo os módulos!